# How to NPM search with regex?

Tags: regex, npm

trying to list all packages available in private registry with `npm search /.* --json`
But output is empty `[]`.
Doc [says](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-search#description) I can use RegEx.

> If a term starts with /, then it's interpreted as a regular expression
> and supports standard JavaScript RegExp syntax. In this case search
> will ignore a trailing / . (Note you must escape or quote many regular
> expression characters in most shells.)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to enclose your pattern with `/` symbols:

```
npm search /.*/ --json
```

Comment: Same behavior empty output. Did that

Comment: Oh and it seems that you should swap `--json` key and expression in command line.

Comment: like this - `npm search --json /.*/`? does not work either. but if I remove `--json` it says `No matches found for "/.*/"`

Comment: Looks better. And if you try it without trailing `/` symbol?

Comment: nah, does nothing

Comment: Does `npm ls` has any results?

Comment: No, but `npm search @myscope --json` does. result -> `[list of all my packages that are in private registry]`